# Hypergeometric sum specific value

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, hypergeometric-functions

How to show?
$${}_2F_1(1,1;\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) = 2 + \frac{\pi}{2} $$

It numerically is very close, came up when evaluating:

$$ \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1 \times 2}{1 \times 3} + \frac{1 \times 2 \times 3}{1 \times 3 \times 5} + \frac{1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4}{1 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7} + \cdots = 1 + \frac{\pi}{2} ~ ?$$

I am missing something trivial, I am sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to showing that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n!}{(2n-1)!!}=\frac\pi2$ , which, after multiplying both the

numerator and the denominator with $(2n)!!=2^n\,n!$, and taking into account that $\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!^2}=$

$=\displaystyle{2n\choose n}$, can be rewritten as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n}{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}}=\frac\pi2$ , which can ultimately be deduced from the

wider identity $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}n^2}=2\arcsin^2x$, itself ultimately a consequence of integrating 
 the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) between the [binomial series expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) of $\arcsin'x=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and

that of its primitive. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the general formula from Brychkov, Prudnikov, Marichev, Integral and Series, Vol.3:
$$
_{2}F_{1}(1,1;\frac{1}{2};x)=(1-x)^{-1}\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{x}\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\right)
$$
and put in it $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your result can be proved very easily by using a result given in Brychkov, Prudnikov, Marichev, Integral and Series, Vol.3, p-91, $ 7.3.7.3 by taking a = b = 1.
For more results of this type, send an e-mail to me for my research paper.
All the very best,
Arjun K. Rathie,
India,
e-mail address: akrathie@gmail.com